# For loop - Leap year input

Tags: python, for-loop

could anyone please help me with a current problem Im having... Its a leap year exercise.

● Write a program to input a year and a number of years.

● Then determine and display which of those years were or will be leap
years.

Example:
What year do you want to start with?   -   1994

How many years do you want to check?  -     8

1994 isn’t a leap year
1995 isn’t a leap year
1996 is a leap year
1997 isn’t a leap year
1998 isn’t a leap year
1999 isn’t a leap year
2000 is a leap year
2001 isn’t a leap year

I cant seem to get my years to display there own value of being a leap year or not....this is the code i have so far:

```
year = int(input("Please enter the year you would like to start checking leap years from."))
total_years = int(input("Please enter over how many years you would like to check."))
leap_year= 0

if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):   
   leap_year = ("this is a leap year")

else:
   leap_year = ("this is not a leap year")

for a in range (0,total_years):
    print(year + a, leap_year)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Are you getting any error messages? If the code runs, can you post the output? Python is a tab-sensitive language (i.e. tabs matter). The formatting of your code doesn't seem correct but that might be a copy/paste problem

Comment: It is a copy paste problem... Sorry. The code runs but it displays the years correctly but only takes the value of the initial year that you inout and adds that value to all of the years...

Comment: If 1992 is input... (1992 is a leap year) Over 3 years it displays :

Comment: 1992 is a leap year.    1993 is a leap year.     1994 is a leap year........ If input 1991 (1991 is not a leap year). It displays: 1991 is not a leap year.     1992 is not a leap year.     1993 is not a leap year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-else block that checks for leap year should be inside the for loop. It's currently outside the for loop so it checks the first year you enter and the for loop simply prints the result for the first year `total_years` number of times.

So, to fix your code, try something like this:

```
year = int(input("Please enter the year you would like to start checking leap years from."))
total_years = int(input("Please enter over how many years you would like to check."))

def is_leap_year(year):
    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
       return True
    else:
       return False

for a in range (0, total_years):
    if is_leap_year(year+a):
        print("this is a leap year")
    else:
        print("this is not a leap year")
```

Comment: Ok... Thank you could you show me how you would code it? Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: Yup, I just posted one way to do it. I put the leap year checking code into a function and call that function from the for loop

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much its perfect. Just ran it now and it works perfectly.... Only thing I changed was your print statements to display the year and over how many years:

Comment: print (a +  year, "this is a leap year")                                          else:                                                                                           print (a + year, "this is not a leap year")

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the logic for checking the years into the loop. For example like so:

```py
start_year = int(input("Please select a starting year: "))
num_of_years = int(input("Please select how many years you'd like to check: "))
end_year = start_year + num_of_years

# The formula I used below to determine when a year is a leap year was copied from emrah-diril in this thread

for year in range(start_year-1, end_year):
    year += 1    
    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
        print ("{}: Is a leap year".format(year))
    else:
        print (year)
```

Answer (score -1):

## python

```
start_year = int(input("Please enter the year you would like to start checking leap years from: "))
total_years = int(input("Please enter over how many years you would like to check: ")) 

for year in range(start_year, start_year + total_years):

        if year % 4 == 0:       
                print(f"{year} is a leap year") 
        else:
                print (f"{year} is not a leap year")
```

Comment: This is a simplified answer to your question.